# Where to download Jquery GalleryView New Version? I cant find it!

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, download

Very simple question! ha?
I can't download the latest version of GalleryView plugin.I have version 1.1 but it is so old. 
the plugin page in jquery website: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/galleryview
and the plugin homepage is here: http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview

Comment: If the answer I left was what you were looking for, please select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zipped file is located [here](http://galleryview.googlecode.com/files/galleryview-2.1.1.zip). This is the SHA1 Checksum: 48b7d177643b01ba7129bf213176db24910b216c to verify the file

Answer (score 1):

In case someone tries to find **GalleryView** and finds out the original homepage of the project is no longer working, here is an update.

Some time ago, around the beginning of May 2011, the original website ([spaceforaname.com/galleryview](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview)) stopped working and is still unavailable. Fortunately, I have downloaded a copy of the newest version (**GalleryView 3.0 Beta3**) a couple days earlier and was able to put it on the Internet again, on my own.

Here is the **latest copy of the script** (as mentioned above: *GalleryView 3.0 Beta3*), downloaded from the official homepage some days before it went down: https://github.com/tadeck/GalleryView

Enjoy!

PS. If anyone cares to develop it further (and fix some problems that the original script had), I would be happy to merge the changes on GitHub.